# ASP.Net Identity number of roles and performance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We have an development scope that requires a very granular permission system. The system itself is quite large and complex, split into different modules based on functionality.

After looking through the requirements my guess is that we will need at least 1,000 roles, but possibly 2,000-3,000.

Most users will only have a very small subset of these roles (maybe 20-30) but there will be some users that may have just about all of them.

My question is should I expect any performance or limitation issues implementing this many roles using ASP.Net Identity?

Comment: There isn't really an answer to this beyond "it depends". Is there a specific area of concern?

Comment: For example, if there are 2,000 roles and a user is assigned all 2,000, should I expect any errors or can it handle these types of numbers? Secondly will the requests start to get slow with that many roles? My understanding is that the cookies are sent to the server on every request, so I'm concerned that's a potentially large amount of data to have to sent/received on every request.

Comment: I wouldn't put that many roles into the cookie, no. However with 2-3k roles I suspect you are treating roles incorrectly.

Comment: I second with @Shoe, something does not look correct. If you somehow make the system work with those many roles, maintenance would be a nightmare. You should consider redesigning the solution, may be a role group would help.

Comment: You should look into extending claims instead of roles. 1 user should be assigned 1 role.

Comment: looks like you are using roles to store each permission. Am i right? If yes then don't use create permissions separately and assign each role some permissions, so that roles contain sets of permissions, like admin role will have all permissions and then user will only be assigned one role.